# List tests with Nose in a machine-readable form

Tags: python, testing, nose

I know I can

- list what tests would run with `nosetests --collect-only`
- and run particular test with `nosetests path/to/module:TestClass.test_method`.

But I don't know how to combine these two steps.  The output from "--collect-only" mode outputs the test docstrings, which is not usable for the other syntax.

I would like to do something like this somewhere in my bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

nosetests --some-mode | while read test_spec;
do
    nosetests $test_spec
    # i.e. nosetest test/SomeTest:ATestSomeClass.test_something
    # and then do something else with $? and $test_spec
done
```

So is there "--some-mode" like this?  Or another way to obtain list of `test_spec`s?

---

Background is that I have a test suite from an upstream project which is laid out to run by simply calling nosetests.  However, in our situation it would make lot of sense to perform tests separately (even at the cost of losing ability to parallelize).

I could catch the output and parse it but that's dirty and would not allow early termination.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `nosetests --with-xunit` to output XUnit-formatted XML representation of test results, which will all pass when `--collect-only` is used. You'll have `nosetests.xml` to work with so that you do not have to rely on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

I have put together [a Perl script](https://github.com/AloisMahdal/minions/blob/master/bin/noselist) that naively parses debug output from `nosetests -vvv --collect-only` and reports it so that it can be used as above (`noselist | while read test_spec;`...).

It works for me now, althought it's kind of a hack so I'd rather have nosetests be able to do this, or have a more sane utility script, e.g. using internal Nose library.